# Espaço entre texto e bordas da tabela

Tags: html, css, tabela-html

Como eu retiro ou reduzo o espaço entre o texto e as bordas superiores e inferiores da tabela?

Preciso que fique mais próxima do texto pois tenho um formulário grande e com esses espaços não cabe em uma folha para impressão.

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding=".666" cellspacing=".666" style="line-height:.75px; width:500px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <p>primeira</p>

            <p>segunda</p>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: figura com os espaços que quero retirar destacados em vermelho]

Answer (score 2):

> Essa resposta é voltada tanto para o autor da pergunta como para
> os outros autores de respostas. É de difícil escrita então qualquer
> contribuição será bem-vinda.

## Avaliando as outras respostas

As duas outras respostas estão erradas:

*Uma resposta é [incompleta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/517513/137387)*

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding=".666" cellspacing=".666" style="line-height:.75px; width:500px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>primeira</p>

        <p>segunda</p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

*A outra resposta [não faz sentido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/517549/137387).*

```css
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding=".666" cellspacing=".666" style="line-height:.75px; width:500px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>primeira</p>

        <p>segunda</p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Então vou aproveitar a resposta incompleta e apresentar uma solução.

## CSS inline

Ambas as respostas parecem não perceber que o usuário aplicou uma estilização em linha a sua tabela:

```html
style="line-height:.75px; width:500px"
```

A primeira providência que um AR deveria tomar seria orientar o usuário a remover o CSS inline já que não é recomendado, esse tipo de estilização torna difícil o trabalho de manutenção da página pois dificulta a leitura e a compreensão da página como um todo. A prova desse argumento é foi que ambos os ARs ignoraram esse CSS.

*O mesmo código da pergunta passando o CSS inline para folha de estilos:*

```css
table{
  line-height:.75px; 
  width:500px
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding=".666" cellspacing=".666">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>primeira</p>

        <p>segunda</p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

## Entendendo o que foi feito

Basicamente o AP personalizou duas propriedades de sua tabela:

- [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) que define a distância entre as linhas de conteúdo de texto dentro de um elemento.
- [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/width) que determina a largura da área de conteúdo de um elemento.

Então é possível deduzir que o AP fixou uma largura para a tabela e de forma equivocada, tentou fazer com que o conteúdo de texto da tabela se contraísse.

## Aproveitando a resposta incompleta e a transformando em solução

Restaure o valor de `line-height` para o valor padrão:

```css
line-height: normal;
```

Crie uma regra que remova as margens dos parágrafos pertencente a tabela e que não afete os parágrafos fora da tabela:

```css
td p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

*Juntando em uma solução:*

```css
td {
  line-height: normal;
  width: 500px
}

td p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding=".666" cellspacing=".666">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>primeira</p>

        <p>segunda</p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>primeiro parágrafo não afetado pelo estilo</p>
<p>segundo parágrafo não afetado pelo estilo</p>
```

Comment: Se o autor da resposta incompleta quiser consertar e restaurar a sua resposta eu não tenho problema algum em remover essa minha resposta caso solicitado.

Answer (score -2):

Use o Padding pra separar por dentro o espaço

```
td{
  padding: 5px;
}
```